# How do I get xmonad to run with the GNOME fallback session?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, xmonad, gnome-classic

I'm not having luck getting XMonad to run in 11.10 (x64, fresh install) with a gnome fallback session. I've tried adapting the instructions from

http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-lucid/

and

http://markhansen.co.nz/xmonad-ubuntu-oneiric/

but with no luck. If anyone has ideas, I'd like to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix: Log in, then execute `killall metacity & xmonad`.

It seems to work, though I'm having intermittent keyboard and mouse issues that may or may not be related to this solution.

Also, given that this works, you'd think I could just swap out the window manager value in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session, but when I change the value, nothing happens.

Comment: Tricky.  I'll upvote these when I have more votes, but if you do make more progress, please add updates -- I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 5):

## How to use a custom window manager with the GNOME Classic session in 11.10

Exemplified with the sawfish window manager (sorry, I don't use xmonad).

### 1. Fix gnome-classic.session

There seems to be
[a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/885939)
in gnome-classic.session. Here's how to fix it:

Edit the system file
/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session
directly or make a copy in your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/.config/gnome-session/sessions
cp -ai /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome-classic.session ~/.config/gnome-session/sessions/
```

Make this change:

```
 [GNOME Session]
 Name=GNOME Classic
 RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
-RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;
+RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
 DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm
 DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
 IsRunnableHelper=/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated
 FallbackSession=gnome-fallback
 DesktopName=GNOME
```

### 2.1. Alternative 1: Set WINDOW_MANAGER in ~/.gnomerc

**2.1.a. Create/edit ~/.gnomerc and add this:**

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER=sawfish
```

Replace "sawfish" in this example with the window manager you want to use. If you now log in with the "GNOME Classic" session, you will get your chosen window manager.

**2.1.b. Faster startup:**

If you experience a 30 second delay at login with the above solution, the following will fix that (this might just be a sawfish issue).

Make a startup script, e.g. ~/bin/my-gnome-wm:

```
#!/bin/bash
sawfish &
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod u+x ~/bin/my-gnome-wm
```

Change ~/.gnomerc to this:

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER="$HOME/bin/my-gnome-wm"
```

### 2.2. Alternative 2: Use sawfish.desktop

**2.2.a. Edit gnome-classic.session again:**

```
 [GNOME Session]
 Name=GNOME Classic
 RequiredComponents=gnome-panel;gnome-settings-daemon;
 RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
-DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm
+DefaultProvider-windowmanager=sawfish
 DefaultProvider-notifications=notify-osd
 IsRunnableHelper=/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-accelerated
 FallbackSession=gnome-fallback
 DesktopName=GNOME
```

Replace "sawfish" in this example with the window manager you want to use. This requires a file like "sawfish.desktop" to be installed in the correct location, e.g. /usr/share/applications/sawfish.desktop.

**2.2.b. Faster startup:**

If you experience a 30 second delay at login with the above solution, the following will fix that (this might just be a sawfish issue).

Edit the system file
/usr/share/applications/sawfish.desktop
directly or make a copy in your home directory:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/applications
cp -ai /usr/share/applications/sawfish.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Make this change:

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Name=Sawfish
 Name[el]=Ðñéïíüøáñï (Sawfish)

 Type=Application
-Exec=sawfish
+Exec=bash -c 'sawfish&'
 TryExec=sawfish

 Terminal=false
 NoDisplay=true

 X-GNOME-WMName=Sawfish
 X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager
 X-GNOME-Provides=windowmanager
 X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
```

### Notes

With DefaultProvider-windowmanager=gnome-wm and without setting WINDOW_MANAGER in .gnomerc, we seem to get both Unity and GNOME Classic at the same time, on top of each other!

This entry in ~/.xsession-errors probably says something about why there is a 30 second delay:

```
gnome-session[23870]: WARNING: Application 'gnome-wm.desktop' failed to register before timeout
```

Why create the my-gnome-wm script? Because this doesn't seem to work:

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER='/usr/bin/sawfish&'
```

Neither does this:

```
export WINDOW_MANAGER='bash -c "/usr/bin/sawfish&"'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer, nice to get the whole pictures of what happening after spend times doing trial-error...

Answer (score 1):

For newer Ubuntu versions (e.g. 15.04), [this](https://github.com/Gekkio/gnome-session-xmonad) repository is available.  To install the needed files:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gekkio/xmonad
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-xmonad
```

---

For Ubuntu 12.04, it almost works "out of the box" -- you need to install gnome panel manually:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-panel

and then you can log in using the "GNOME with Xmonad" session from the login screen.

(source: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Using_xmonad_in_Gnome#Ubuntu_Precise)