# Exotic graphical user interfaces for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, interface

What non-traditional graphical user interfaces **currently run** on Ubuntu?

I don't mean hand-wringing over Gnome Shell and Unity, nor behind-the-scenes changes like Wayland. I mean *something that the end user would experience as completely different*: new interface paradigms (not just smartphone-like), [3D interfaces](http://nooface.net/3dui.shtml) [1], clones of [BumpTop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BumpTop) or [Microsoft Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob), wildly animated windows and widgets, and [the kinds of things you might see only in movies](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/film-ui-bloopers.html).

Please include:

- ***visuals:*** screenshots, links to screenshots or links to videos that demonstrate the difference between this and a traditional interface
- ***instructions:*** (or a link to instructions) on how to install them on the current version of Ubuntu

(I am not looking for examples that require exotic input devices. Something you could install and play with on a regular desktop or laptop machine.)

[1] ["It's a UNIX system, I know this!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFUlAQZB9Ng)

Comment: The interface on the unix system was an actual interface called fsn ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsn )

Comment: I think I'm looking for things that you **wouldn't** called a desktop environment -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment - unless it was a DE with pixies dancing all over

Answer (score 2):

[xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) is quite a popular window tiling manager and is compatible with Ubuntu 11.10. It's especially useful for managing multiple workspaces and multiple monitors.

Comment: instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69511/how-do-i-get-xmonad-to-run-with-the-gnome-fallback-session

Answer (score 0):

Different paradigms are Enlightenment (aka E17) and ROXDesktop, another approach are 'tiling window managers' which I can't recommend, as there are many. E17 is rather pretty and modern.

Comment: instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16932/how-do-i-install-enlightenment-e17

Comment: screenshot and a bit of explanation: http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/wiki/AboutEnlightenment

Comment: rox screenshots: http://roscidus.com/desktop/screenshots

Comment: rox ubuntu instructions (seem a bit dated): http://roscidus.com/desktop/Ubuntu