# Gnome Xmonad broken after upgraded to 14.10

Tags: gnome, xmonad

After upgraded to 14.10, gnome-settings-daemon cannot be loaded properly /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session.  is there anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a more detailed solution based on Jianingy answer. It fixes a few issues I was having after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10. The issues it's fixing include:

- Multimedia keys not working
- Display settings in Gnome-control-center not working

You need to add `DesktopName=Unity` to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session`.

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Xmonad/GNOME
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;gnome-panel;xmonad
DesktopName=Unity
```

Also, regarding `dbus-send` changes in Ubuntu 14.10, you have to use `--print-reply=literal` instead of `--print-reply=string`. I have added that to my `xmonad.hs` and I define main as `main = xmonad $ gnomeConfig2`.

```python
import XMonad.Config.Desktop
import XMonad.Util.Run (safeSpawn)

import qualified Data.Map as M

import System.Environment (getEnvironment)

data RescreenToggleState = RescreenToggleState Bool deriving Typeable
instance ExtensionClass RescreenToggleState where
  initialValue = RescreenToggleState True

gnomeConfig2 = desktopConfig
    { terminal = "gnome-terminal"
    , keys     = gnomeKeys <+> keys desktopConfig
    , startupHook = gnomeRegister2 >> startupHook desktopConfig }

gnomeKeys (XConfig {modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
    [ ((modm, xK_p), gnomeRun)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_q), spawn "gnome-session-save --kill") ]

-- | Register xmonad with gnome. 'dbus-send' must be in the $PATH with which
-- xmonad is started.
--
-- This action reduces a delay on startup only only if you have configured
-- gnome-session>=2.26: to start xmonad with a command as such:
--
-- > gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager xmonad --type string
gnomeRegister2 :: MonadIO m => m ()
gnomeRegister2 = io $ do
    x <- lookup "DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID" `fmap` getEnvironment
    whenJust x $ \sessionId -> safeSpawn "dbus-send"
            ["--session"
            ,"--print-reply=literal"
            ,"--dest=org.gnome.SessionManager"
            ,"/org/gnome/SessionManager"
            ,"org.gnome.SessionManager.RegisterClient"
            ,"string:xmonad"
            ,"string:"++sessionId]
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I have rephrased my answer. I was trying to give more details on how to fix the issue.

Comment: I tested this answer, while it does seem to fix gnome-control-manager, it did not cause my media keys to start working again.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution.

First of all, Starting from 14.10. Many unity and gnome application configurations ( those *.desktop in /usr/share/applications and /etc/xdg/autostart ) start to include a "OnlyShowIn=Unity". Therefore we have to add a desktopname=unity to /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/xmonad.session in order to let those applications run.

Second, cmd 'dbus-send --print-reply=string' now have to be 'dbus-send --print-reply=literal'. therefore, old xmonad gnomeConfig cannot register xmonad as a wm. we have to change the dbus-send command from =string to =literal.

Answer (score 1):

- https://gist.github.com/bewest/46b849da04684f0ce401
- http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/12/ubuntu-utopic-upgrade-xmonad/comment-page-1/

The `--print-reply=string` syntax causes an error.
The name of the application that needs to be "registered" is not `xmonad`, but `xmonad.desktop`.
I wound up creating a `~/.xmonad/hooks` file with the following command in it:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.SessionManager /org/gnome/SessionManager org.gnome.SessionManager.RegisterClient string:xmonad.desktop string:$DESKTOP_AUTO_START_ID
```

I also found the previous fix, setting `DesktopName=Unity` causes the `gnome-control-center` to be used properly.

Comment: How do you run the `~/.xmonad/hooks` script?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple way to workaround the "xmonad fails to register" problem (addressed in other answers by using xmonad hooks or writing `gnomeRegister2`): in the `xmonad.desktop` file, replace `Exec=xmonad` with `Exec=sh -c "xmonad &"`. This results in a very fast startup -- I got the idea [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/78123/56280) -- but it might break other things.

The `DesktopName=Unity` part is still essential.

## UPDATE (16 November 2015)

I regularly fight XMonad + Gnome when I upgrade Ubuntu. My config files are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ntc2/conf), in case anyone would like to see how I've most recently gotten XMonad and Gnome to play nice together.

As of 16 November 2015, the important files are

- `~/.xsession`: https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/master/dot.xsession
- Gnome `*.desktop` files: https://github.com/ntc2/conf/tree/master/dot.local/share/applications (I maintain my XMonad + Gnome config in my home dir, without having to edit any system `*.desktop` files; see my [conf install script](https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/master/install-conf.py) for where these files go).
- Gnome `*.session` file: https://github.com/ntc2/conf/blob/master/dot.config/gnome-session/sessions/local-xmonad-session.session

For Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10, the most important, and hardest to discover change was to add `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` to my `~/.xsession`:

```
# Without setting this explicitly, it gets te value "Gnome", which
# makes `unity-settings-daemon` fail to start and we get
# `gnome-settings-daemon` instead. Not sure what this variable does,
# but I got the hint here:
# https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=729575.
#
# Setting to values other than "Unity" -- e.g. "default", which `env`
# tells me is the value of related variables, or "GNOME-Flashback",
# which is the `DesktopName` I might suspect here -- I get weird
# behavior, e.g. none of the dock items appear in the Gnome panel.
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity
```

Also, to get graphical notifications on e.g. volume key presses and screen brightness adjustment, I needed to install the `notify-osd` package.

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned it briefly in the gist, but I found in the XMonad docs, that the startup hook is executed automatically given, this config:

`, startupHook = execScriptHook "startup"`

This causes the shell script to be run automatically, which I found easier than monkeypatching the haskell hook.

http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-Script.html

---

## XMonad.Hooks.Script

### Script Hook Interface

Provides a simple interface for running a ~/.xmonad/hooks script with the name of a hook.

### Synopsis

### Usage

This module allows you to run a centrally located script with the text name of a hook. The script is assumed to be located at ~/.xmonad/hooks.

For example, if you wanted to run the hook startup in your script every time your startup hook ran, you could modify your xmonad config as such:

`main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
   ...
   startupHook = execScriptHook "startup"
   ...
   }`

Now, every time the startup hook runs, the command `~/.xmonad/hooks startup` will also.

---